# how to run scheduler utility in web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, scheduling

I have the web application in visual studio web express and having db in sql server express.
I want to perform insert 100 records on 5:00 PM daily.web application is developed in asp.net MVC and vb.net. and deployed on server machine with IIS 7.5. what logic i should follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me i'm using this approach and it's good till now :)

I've enum with Tasks to do and the time for the task to restart and this time in seconds like this:

```
public enum ScheduledTasks
{
    CleanGameRequests = 120,
    AnotherTask = 30,
}
```

Then i start all my tasks in the `Application_Start` to ensure that the task will execute while my application is run

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...............
        // Add the tasks on Application starts
        AddTask(ScheduledTasks.CleanGameRequests);
        AddTask(ScheduledTasks.AnotherTask);
    }
```

OK now here is the trick :)

in the AddTask method i just add new empty item to cache and set the AbsoluteExpiration for it according to the task time and the call the suitable method for this task.

Actually my i couldn't explain the idea very clear but here is the code:

```
    private static CacheItemRemovedCallback _onCacheRemove;
    private void AddTask(ScheduledTasks task)
    {
        // Add my `CacheItemRemoved` method to be called on cache removed
        _onCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
        // Add new key to the cache with the name of this task 
        // and Expiration time acccordin to the task
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(task.ToString(), (int)task, null,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((int)task), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, _onCacheRemove);
    }
```

Then all I've to do is to select suitable method for each task in the `CacheItemRemoved` method :

```
    public void CacheItemRemoved(string key, object time, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
    {
        //Get Task enum object
        var task = (ScheduledTasks)Enum.Parse(typeof(ScheduledTasks), key);
        // Select the suitable method to depending on the Task Enum object
        switch (task)
        {
            case ScheduledTasks.CleanGameRequests:
                GameRequest.CleanUp();
                break;
            case ScheduledTasks.AnotherTask:
                Service.AnotherTask();
                break;
        }
        // Don't forget to re-add the task to the cache to do it again and again
        AddTask(task);
    }
```

Last thing remain for your case is to check the time if it's 5:00 PM and  i advice you to put this check in your Service class.

Hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using *Sql server express* edition you can't create scheduled jobs in sql side. But you can try other options like.

1. [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Service Broker approach](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express)
3. Windows services (If your hosting provider allows)

Comment: ok, good options. but as per logically, once i host/deploy the web application on server machine, and I am writting the utility method and call it on system time let say 5:00 pm

Comment: You can do that through the Quartz.Net, it helps you to create job classes and methods where you can write all your code. It also has variety of options to control the scheduled time and more.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think it is best way but, its simple auto function call which happened on exact 5:00 pm. and web application is hosted on server itself where db is exist.